# How to add a DiagnosticAnalyzer in Visual Studio 2017 manually

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, roslyn

I work on a C# DiagnosticAnalyzer for Visual Studio 2017.

The Template for "Analyzer with Code Fix (.Net Standard)" works great, my created Analyzer is installed in the experimental Instance of Visual Studio.

Is it possible to add my Analyzer to Solutions/Projects without any support of Vsix templates, i.e. copy the Analyzer Dlls to a certain folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to add my Analyzer to Solutions/Projects without any support of Vsix templates?

Yes, you can add analyzers via **NuGet** to a specific solution or project.

> [Can I] copy the Analyzer Dlls to a certain folder?

As far as I know this is not supported. The [official documentation on installing Roslyn analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/install-roslyn-analyzers) only mentions **NuGet** and **VSIX**.